# FastAPI authorization by resource owners

Tags: python, authentication, jwt, authorization, fastapi

I am building a system in which i have several entities:

- User
- Trainer
- Trainee (Belong to a trainer)

and other entities that belong to either the trainer / trainee

I want to create a permission system where a trainer can create/edit/update/delete resources of his trainees and also the current logged in trainee can alter his own resources

My app is build similar to the pattern of[Netflix dispatch project](https://github.dev/Netflix/dispatch/tree/master/src/dispatch)

So for example if i am logged in as a trainer and i am calling this api UPDATE:"/some-resource/{resource_id}"

for each resource i need to create a dependency that will fetch the resource by the id, Fetch the trainer by the current user id and check if the resource trainee_id column is a part of the trainer trainees list

This approach seem not scalable at all but i can't manage to think of any other good alternative.

I tried implementing the mechanism of the authorization but it seems over complicated, too much boilerplate code and not scalable:

The implementation looks for example like that:
`class CurrentTraineePermission(BasePermission):
async def has_required_permissions(self, request: Request) -> bool:
if self.role is not UserRoles.trainee:
return False

```
    trainee_id = request.path_params.get(
        "trainee_id", (await self.get_body()).get("traineeId")
    )

    if not trainee_id:
        return False

    # TODO: CONSIDER PUTTING THIS INFO IN TOKEN TO NOT ACCESS DB
    trainee = trainee_service.get_by_user_id(
        db_session=request.state.db, user_id=self.user_id
    )

    if not trainee:
        return False

    return trainee.id == trainee_id
```

class TraineeBelongToTrainerPermission(BasePermission):
async def has_required_permissions(self, request: Request) -> bool:
if self.role is not UserRoles.trainer:
return False

```
    trainee_id = request.path_params.get(
        "trainee_id", (await self.get_body()).get("traineeId")
    )

    trainee = trainee_service.get(
        db_session=request.state.db, trainee_id=trainee_id
    )

    trainer = trainer_service.get_by_user_id(
        db_session=request.state.db, user_id=self.user_id
    )

    return trainee.trainer_id == trainer.id
```

class CreateOwnerPermission(BasePermission):
async def has_required_permissions(self, request: Request) -> bool:
return await any_permission(
permissions=[
TraineeBelongToTrainerPermission,
CurrentTraineePermission,
],
request=request,
)

class ResourceOwnerPermission(BasePermission):
async def has_required_permissions(self, request: Request) -> bool:
if not await any_permission(
permissions=[
TraineeBelongToTrainerPermission,
CurrentTraineePermission,
],
request=request,
):
return False

```
    resource_id = request.path_params.get(
        "resource_id", (await self.get_body()).get("resourceId")
    )
    
    trainee_id = request.path_params.get(
        "trainee_id", (await self.get_body()).get("traineeId")
    )
    
    resource = resource_service.get(resource_id=resource_id)
    
    if not resource:
        return False
    
    return resource.trainee_id == trainee_id`
```

Comment: Why do you think that "This approach seem not scalable at all but i can't manage to think of any other good alternative."? As long as you have proper indexes on your columns and can look them up quickly, it should work perfectly fine. Performance optimizations should _generally_ be made when you know where the performance problems are - be careful about premature optimizations.